# Use std::string_view size in template parameter from NTTP constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple C++20 compile-time string type that is defined like this:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class compile_time_string_storage
{
  public:
    constexpr compile_time_string_storage(std::array<char, N> str) noexcept
      : value(str)
    {
    }

    constexpr compile_time_string_storage(const char (&str)[N]) noexcept
    {
        std::copy_n(str, N, value.begin());
    }

    constexpr compile_time_string_storage(char c) noexcept
      : value{ c }
    {
    }

    std::array<char, N> value;
};

compile_time_string_storage(char)->compile_time_string_storage<1>;

template<compile_time_string_storage S>
class str
{
  public:
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr static std::string_view get() noexcept
    {
        return { S.value.data(), size_ };
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr static std::size_t size() noexcept { return size_; }

  private:
    constexpr static std::size_t calculate_size() noexcept
    {
        auto count = std::size_t{ 0 };
        for (; count < S.value.size(); ++count) {
            if (S.value[count] == '\0') {
                break;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    constexpr static std::size_t size_ = calculate_size();
};
```

This works.  However I would like to add support of construction via `std::string_view`, which in principle should be straightforward as it can be constexpr-constructed, but I'm struggling.

Initially I added a constexpr constructor overload to `compile_time_string_storage` with a deduction guide:

```
<source>:55:80: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
compile_time_string_storage(std::string_view str)->compile_time_string_storage<str.size()>;
                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The constructor argument can't be used in a compile-time context.  I then tried using the deduction guide as 'tag' I can specialise on:

```
constexpr auto string_view_tag = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();

template<>
class compile_time_string_storage<string_view_tag>
{
public:
    constexpr compile_time_string_storage(std::string_view str) : value(str)
    {}

    std::string_view value;
};

compile_time_string_storage(std::string_view)->compile_time_string_storage<string_view_tag>;
```

Nope, can't use that:

```
<source>:52:22: note: 'compile_time_string_storage<string_view_tag>' is not a structural type because it has a non-static data member of non-structural type 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>')
    std::string_view value;
                     ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../include/c++/11.2.0/string_view:510:18: note: 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>') is not a structural type because it has a non-static data member that is not public
      size_t        _M_len;
                    ^
```

OK, what if I make an equivalent 'structural' version of `std::string_view`?

```
struct str_view
{
    constexpr str_view(std::string_view str) : data_{str.data()}, size_{str.size()}
    {}

    constexpr const char* const data() const noexcept { return data_; }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return size_; }

    const char* data_;
    std::size_t size_;
};

template<>
class compile_time_string_storage<string_view_tag>
{
public:
    constexpr compile_time_string_storage(std::string_view str) : value(str)
    {}

    str_view value;
};
```

[Nope](https://godbolt.org/z/68zorhTKz).

```
<source>:88:23: error: pointer to subobject of string literal is not allowed in a template argument
    static_assert(str<"hello"sv>::get() == "hello");
                      ^
```

Is there a way of using a `std::string_view` to initialise `compile_time_string_storage`?

I'm currently using the deduction guide to set a fixed value for `N` (set by a compiler define), which works in the sense that the compiler is smart enough to just keep the original string data in static storage rather than the `std::array` contents.  But it's hack as you need to know the maximum string length you'll need up front, and it's just not *right*.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There's a reason we pass `const char (&)[N]` as the constructor parameter, the length has to be encoded in the type to affect the class' template argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of using a `std::string_view` to initialise `compile_time_string_storage`?

Your problem is that you seem to want a number of things that cannot all go together. You want:

1. To create a `compile_time_string_storage` from a `constexpr` `string_view` *without* specifying the size explicitly as a template parameter.
2. To have the `compile_time_string_storage` provide an array of N characters of storage for the string.

You cannot have both. So long as `compile_time_string_storage` has a size template parameter that must be filled in by a property of a non-template parameter, this will not work. Function parameters, and therefore members of them, are not `constexpr`.

Your last attempt drops #2, and that approach can work. However, you ran into a separate problem: pointers to string literals *cannot* be used as template parameters. You cannot smuggle them into template parameters as members of some other object either.

It would have worked if you used a stack array of strings as your source for the `string_view`. Of course, then your "compile_time_string_storage` would be a *lie*, because it would not actually store the string. It would be referencing existing storage that may or may not exist by the time someone uses the string.

If your ultimate goal requires the ability to shove a string literal pointer into this class *without* copying characters, give it up. The standard expressly forbids it. So you're left with having the string store an array.

An array whose size *cannot* come from a function parameter.

So your only recourse is to do it manually: take the `constexpr string_view`, get its size, and pass that size explicitly as a template parameter:

```
constexpr compile_time_string_storage<some_constexpr_string_view.size()> var(some_constexpr_string_view);
```

It's ugly, but that's your only option.

Alternatively, avoid `string_view` altogether and use a `span<char const, N>` constructed from a string literal. `span` is able to maintain the size of the span as a template parameter, which in turn allows your `compile_time_string_storage` to extract it without having to manually insert the template argument.